# Embedded YouTube video display thumbnail image

Tags: css, youtube

I've embedded a YouTube video. I have no control over the particular video on YouTube. In Safari it looks great, but in Chrome and Firefox a horrible image is displayed. I believe this is called a "thumbnail" image? How can I get the thumbnail to display on all browsers?

[image]

[image]

I've noticed in Chrome and Firefox that if I don't alter the size of the video then the thumbnail image works. But strangely it is a different image to the one used in Safari:

[image]

I get the above thumbnail if I don't use the following code (which makes the video responsive size)

```
figure {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
    }

iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
```

So my question is, how do I get a thumbnail image to display AND the video be sized responsively?

I've read several posts about YouTube thumbnail images, but I don't think they explain how to actually get it to display before someone clicks the video
[How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api/2068371#2068371)

Here's the embed code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M6F5Cu-VxJc?si=adRP_pz0P_s8LLjt" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: YouTube returns different thumbnail images based on the size of the iframe. Your video seems to not have a high resolution version (`maxresdefault.webp`) which is why it shows the 3 dot image. Your css should work assuming you have the `iframe` wrapped in a `figure`, but you should remove the `width` and `height` from the `iframe` code.

Comment: Thank you. That explains a lot. The thumbnail is displayed until the iframe gets to 640px wide, then, presumably when it would need the high res version, it shows the 3 dots. Any ideas how I get YouTube to make a high res version?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48178125/3550318) helps?

Comment: Hey, thanks, but I don't have access to the YouTube account, so I think I'm stuck.